# R2HTML package changed support for \Sexpr

Tags: r, sweave, cran, r2html

I'm seeing different behaviour with two versions of the R2HTML package in R. With version 2.2.1, I can include R variables in a `\Sexpr`, but in version 2.3.0 I can't. Is there a different way I can call Sweave that will be compatible with both versions of R2HTML?

Here's a sample .Rnw file that shows the problem:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>x is \Sexpr{x}.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's a sample .R file that shows how I call Sweave:

```
library(R2HTML)

x <- 23

Sweave("sample.Rnw", driver=RweaveHTML, syntax="SweaveSyntaxNoweb")
```

When I execute `Rscript sample.R`, I see this error:

```
Writing to file sample.html
Processing code chunks ...
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
Calls: Sweave -> <Anonymous> -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

I have R2HTML version 2.3.0, as I can see by running this in R:

```
installed.packages()[,'Version'][installed.packages()[,'Package']=='R2HTML']
```

If I roll back to R2HTML version 2.2.1, it works fine.

```
$ sudo R CMD REMOVE R2HTML
$ wget http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/R2HTML/R2HTML_2.2.1.tar.gz
$ sudo R CMD INSTALL R2HTML_2.2.1.tar.gz
$ Rscript sample.R && cat sample.html 
Writing to file sample.html
Processing code chunks ...
file  sample.html is completed 
<html>

<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href=R2HTML.css><body>

<p>x is 23.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This package violated CRAN policies and then changed maintainers between these two versions, so it's likely many things changed. I don't see this made as an intentional commit [here](https://github.com/nalimilan/R2HTML/commits/master). It looks like you may want to write [`<Sexpr CODEHERE>`](https://github.com/nalimilan/R2HTML/blob/180c245fa0b4cf2dbd138a1f144a45601f8bb6cc/R/HTMLcore.R#L4340) instead.

Comment: I tried that format, @Thomas, but it didn't work either. I've posted a [Github issue](https://github.com/nalimilan/R2HTML/issues/1), so we'll see whether this feature is even supported. I can't find it in the user manual.